# Gson Object complex with list objects (from json to complex object)

Tags: json, list, gson, android

I got and error when I execute

```
VehiculoCombustiblesResponseDTO respuesta= new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), VehiculoCombustiblesResponseDTO.class);
```

error is:

> Unhandled exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 52 path $.f

this is the json response

```
{"a":5,"b":50,"c":23,"d":"12349","e":2,"f":[{"a":2,"b":"Premium"},{"a":1,"b":"Magna"}]}
```

I have this class

```
public class VehiculoCombustiblesResponseDTO {
    private int a;
    private  int b;

    /**
     * VehiculoId
     * @return
     */
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    /**
     * VehiculoId
     * @return
     */
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    /**
     * CapacidadCombustible
     * @return
     */
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    /**
     * CapacidadCombustible
     * @return
     */
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    /**
     * KilometrajeInicial
     * @return
     */
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
    /**
     * KilometrajeInicial
     * @return
     */
    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    /**
     * NumeroEconomico
     * @return
     */
    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }
    /**
     * NumeroEconomico
     * @return
     */
    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    /**
     * TipoCombustibleId
     * @return
     */
    public int getE() {
        return e;
    }
    /**
     * TipoCombustibleId
     * @return
     */
    public void setE(int e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
    /**
     * TiposCombustible (Listado)
     * @return
     */
    public TiposCombustibleResponseDTO getF() {
        return f;
    }
    /**
     * TiposCombustible (Listado)
     * @return
     */
    public void setF(TiposCombustibleResponseDTO f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    private  int c;
    private  String d;
    private int e;
    private TiposCombustibleResponseDTO f;
}
```

and this other

```
public class TiposCombustibleResponseDTO {

    /**
     * obtiene CombustibleId del servidor
     * @return
     */
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * Establece CombustibleId
     * @param a
     */
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    /**
     * obtiene Descripcion del servidor
     * @return
     */
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    /**
     * Estaclece Descripcion del servidor
     * @param b
     */
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    private int a;
    private String b;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said to Gson: give me object from this JSON, Gson found a object, but the `f` in JSON response is an array, but in your class this field is an object, so this is incompatible.

There is significant difference between JSON object and array:

This is JSON object:

```
{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" }
```

This is JSON array:

```
[
    { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

Notice these brackets: `[]`

**Solution:**

Change `f` field to an array:

```
private TiposCombustibleResponseDTO[] f;
```

Comment: I have added but put the json here :   {"a":5,"b":50,"c":23,"d":"12349","e":2,"f":[{"a":2,"b":"Premium"},{"a":1,"b":"Magna"}]}

Comment: VehiculoCombustibleResponseDTO is a complex object (as you can see in json string)

Comment: I want from json to object

Comment: you have reason I really believe I have f field as List<TiposCombustibleResponseDTO> f I have update it to List and now it worked.

Comment: Gson can automatically wrap array into list. I should have note it :)